# GIS, Mercator projection, calculate Y position

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, gis, projection

I am doing some stuff with GIS(or map), and I know how to calculate Y position from latitude in mercator projection. But I don't know how it comes?

[image]

Why it is ln(tan(x)+sec(x)) ? I couldn't figure out why there is a 'ln'?

I know it is not directly related to programming, but I hope some one could help me understanding about this (better with some pictures to illustrate)

Comment: If it's purely mathematical, why not ask it on Math Overflow?

Comment: This isn't meant to be silly, but this might be too basic for Math Overflow.

Comment: @avpx & John, didn't know there is a "Math Overflow". I am going to ask there right now. Thank you~

Comment: Is there a link to the mathOverflow question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you're asking about the last step in the derivation you've listed. It's the definition of [arctanh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms) combined with some trigonometry identities.